# Code at the beginning of a post is formatted differently between submit and preview

Tags: bug, markdown, status-norepro

```
for (var i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
}
```

When code leads the post, Markdown differs between the preview and the submitted HTML. The submitted HTML does not format the code while the preview does.

Bug does not repro on meta. I ran into the error when first posting this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2274573/edit

However, the revision log seems to be missing, so I can't prove my point.

Comment: FWIW, it's better if you *don't* lead off with a code block - a short introductory sentence will show up on the Questions page and in tooltips on the front page.

Comment: There will be no revision log for revisions made within the first 5 minutes of the initial post, or within 2 minutes of each other for any other edit.

Comment: Add a blank line in front of your code and it will be repro here as well.

Answer (score 1):

can't reproduce this. Underlying source code on meta and SO is identical.

Comment: Here is another repro: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302631/is-it-possible-to-declare-an-alias-with-net-type/2302644#2302644

Answer (score 0):

You can add a few empty lines before the code block as a work around.

Comment: Funny that we all know the workaround, but this bug continues to get closed as No Repro.